# Numpy slicing by array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([4, 3, 2, 1])
b = np.array([1, 2, 4, 3])
c = np.stack((a, b))
i = np.array([0, 1])
print(c[i])
```

I got:

```
[[4 3 2 1]
 [1 2 4 3]]
```

but my expectd output:

```
[4 2]
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: try `print(c[[0,1], [0,1]])`

Comment: `c[np.arange(c.shape[0]), i]`

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem that's exactly what I want, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to achieve here?

`c = [[4 3 2 1] [1 2 4 3]];` from np.stack call

`[c[0][0],c[1][1]]` returns `[4 2]` which is what you want.